# Maximum sum in Array by picking elements

Tags: arrays, dynamic-programming

Given three arrays a[], right[] and left[].

I am trying to find the maximum sum by picking the elements of array such that if ith element is picked, I cannot pick the left[i] consecutive elements which are on the left side of the i and right[i] consecutive elements which are on the right side of i.

```
a[] - indicates value of the array
right[] - right[i] means if element i is picked, we cannot pick right[i] elements that are in right side of i.
left[] - left[i] means if element i is picked, we cannot pick left[i] elements that are in left side of i.
```

> Example -  
> N = 5 
> a[ ] = [1 3 7 3 7]
>  left[ ] = [0 0 2 2 2]
>  right[ ]= [3 0 1
>   0 0]
>
> Answer = 10 (we can pick 2nd and last element)

I am sensing Dynamic programming here. I have already solved problems like maximum sum such that [no two/three elements are adjacent.](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-sum-such-that-no-two-elements-are-adjacent/)
I also tried solving this question by creating the start and finish times of every element and used the [weighted job scheduling algorithm](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/weighted-job-scheduling/).

But I am unable to figure out the correct solution

Note: 1<= N <= 300000

Comment: same problem twice in a day, hmmmm.....

Comment: you can provide the link if it's duplicate

Comment: I am not accusing you.ok? are you in a contest? class assignment?